# conditionally write in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a piece of code that goes through and open several tab-delimited files. Each time the first tab of the line of this opened file starts with four numbers (ex. 0012) I would like to write this line in an array (cell-by-cell).

A sample line that I would like to transfer to an array is shown below:

```
0029 Montana 1970 0922 1133 5.4 CR 620 Eagle 31.9 CAA - 1.10
```

As can be seen in some cases the tab will have "-". I would like that to be transferred. I know I should start like:

```
with open(each_file) as f:
   for line in f:
```

but I need some help with afterwards

Comment: Point of clarification: Python's standard mutable sequence type is `list`, not `array` (there is an `array` module, but that's a special purpose module for when you need to store lots of numeric data that fits in limited precision C types).

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html); it [supports tab separated dialects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab) just fine. For example:

```
import csv

with open(each_file, newline='') as f:
   for row in csv.reader(f, dialect='excel-tab'):
       # On each iteration row is a list containing the fields from a single record
       # properly splitting only on tabs, not spaces, and handling the Excel
       # standard quoting rules when a field might contain tabs or newlines
```